# Search and extract a file from jar. Java

Tags: java, jar

I get jar files from net. I've been able to open it and to search for a file(.txt file) that I need inside it. For doing that I am using JarEntry and method getNextJarEntry(). 
Finally when I identify the file I need I would like to save it in some directory on my disc. I don't know how to do this. The object I have after file identification is JarEntry which corresponds to the file I want to save.
Can anybody suggest me a way how to store the file I need?

My bad, I only have JarInputStream and not the jar itself.

Answer (score 2):

On the original `JarFile` object, you can pass the `JarEntry` and get an `InputStream`:

```
 InputStream    getInputStream(ZipEntry ze)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`JarFile.getInputStream(ZipEntry)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29) method, read all the bytes from the input stream, and write them to a FileOutputStream.

Comment: Actually I don't have JarFile. I have JarInputStream object.

Comment: The read method of JarInputStream (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) reads from the current entry, and returns -1 if the end of the entry has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

You might load the JAR using a custom classloader (`java.net.URLClassloader`), then get the resource using `getResourceAsStream`.